# Is there a way to know the interval number in apscheduler

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

I am scheduling the job like below.

```html
def interval_job():
 if interval_number > 2:
    execute this code.
 
 <interval code execution>


if __name__ == "__main__":

 scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
 scheduler.add_job(lambda: interval_job(), "interval", seconds=args.interval_time)
 scheduler.start()
```

I would like to know which interval is executing and implement logic within scheduled job according to the value of interval number.

Is there anyway to know this interval number? I am open to better solutions as well.

I looked in the documentation [apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/) but couldn't find any mention of interval_number or iteration_count.